# Direct sale smart contract, is this working without security issue?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, crowdsale, price

I want to make a page for direct sale of my token, just like the one in [Loomx](https://loomx.io/purchase/), with a fixed token price (changeable later by me) and immediately transfer token to buyer securely after purchase.

I try to "steal" their smart contract but it's not verified and public. When I try search online, most are [Crowdsale](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol), which seems to be over complicated.

I also found a [direct-corwdsale library](https://github.com/Modular-Network/ethereum-libraries-direct-crowdsale), but it seems not being used widely.

Here's my code which is very simple:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import 'http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';
import 'http://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract Directsale is Ownable {

    uint public tokensPerEther;
    ERC20 public token;
    bool public saleClosed = false;

    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount);

    constructor (
        uint tokenPerEachEther,
        address tokenAddress
    ) public {
        tokensPerEther = tokenPerEachEther * 1 ether;
        token = ERC20(tokenAddress);
    }

    function closeSale() external onlyOwner {
        saleClosed = true;
    }

    function setTokenPrice(uint tokenPerEachEther) external onlyOwner {
       tokensPerEther  = tokenPerEachEther * 1 ether;
    }

    function () payable public {
        require(!saleClosed);
        require(msg.value > 0);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, amount * tokensPerEther);
        emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount);
    }

}
```

Would that be ok and would not cause any security issue?

And, is there any good open-source example including the web3 **javascript**, so I can study with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick answer to my own question, I turned out using the [CappedCrowdsale.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol) and [AllowanceCrowdsale.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale/emission/CappedCrowdsale.sol) from [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity). It should be safe and stable enough, my final code is here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol';
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol';
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/HasNoTokens.sol";

contract CubikCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale, HasNoTokens {

  event RateChange(uint256 amount);

  constructor (uint256 _rate, address _wallet, ERC20 _token, uint256 _cap) public Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token) CappedCrowdsale(_cap) AllowanceCrowdsale(_wallet) {
  }

  function setRate(uint256 _rate) external onlyOwner {
    rate = _rate;
    emit RateChange(_rate);
  }

}
```

For Web3 frontend, I couldn't find a good completed example and eventually wrote my own one [here](https://github.com/Block42World/cubik-crowdsale-frontend).